# cURL and PHP displaying "1"

Tags: php, mysql, database, curl

I have a PHP script with which I want to read servers from database and connect to them with cURL. Servers responds with results from sql query. The problem is that script after each respond from server displays number 1. The ouput looks like this:

> Server 1:     some results
>
> 1Server 2:    some results
>
> 1Server 3:    some results
>
> 1

Here is the code that reads servers from database and connects to them:

```
<?php

$mysql_id = mysql_connect('localhost', 'ms', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('servers', $mysql_id);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$query = "SELECT * FROM svr";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $server[] = $data;
}

mysql_close($mysql_id);

$i = 0;
while($i < $num) {
    $dealer = $server[$i]['dealer'];

    echo $dealer . "<br />";

    $data = "val=a"; //just for testing                                                                    

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                                                                                                       
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    $i++;
}

?>
```

I discovered that 1 is displayed with "echo $result;" and the code for creating response is this:

```
<?php

$mysql_id1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'ms', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('servers', $mysql_id1);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $num2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
    while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $deli[] = $data2;
    }
    $i1 = 0;
    $space = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    while ($i1 < $num2) {
        echo $space . $deli[$i1]['id'] . " ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['artikel'] . " ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['znamka'] . " ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['model'] . " ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['letnik'] . " ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['cena'] . " € ";
        echo $deli[$i1]['zaloga'] . "<br />";
        $i1++;
    }
    echo "<br />";
    mysql_close($mysql_id1);
?>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option. Otherwise cURL will automatically echo the data and just return `true` (which is converted to `1` by echo).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

[PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says,

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

Comment: Life saver. I have added the explanation given by PHP.net for everyone's knowledge. Thanks @Emil! Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFE` or `curl_exec` returns a statuscode and sends the response to stdout:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` shoud be TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly.read the full documentation [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

or you can do

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFE` or else it will return a status-code and sends the response to `stdout`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, if the user can change dealer field or $deli fields you have got stored XSS vulnerability here.

```
 $dealer = $server[$i]['dealer'];
 echo $dealer . "<br />";
 echo $space . $deli[$i1]['id'] . " ";
 ...etc
```

use

```
htmlentities($your fields)
```

to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide an updated version of OP's code. This will help other users understanding the question and answer