# Put JSON content in a JSON file

Tags: php, json, file, server

I'm trying to put a JSON response from an API connection into a JSON file but when I do so I only get the value true in the JSON File.

The API PHP function:

```
public function Get_Reviews(){
    $token =  'CDF494791E05F36531FA0F5F';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;


    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => '[URL]',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

and the code to put the response in a JSON file:

```
    $api = new Reviews();
    $reviews = $api->Get_Reviews();


    $file = "reviews_created.json";
    unlink($file);
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $reviews);
    fclose($fp)
```

When I var_dump($reviews) I get a clean JSON response and I can copy that manually in a JSON file but I need to make this dynamic.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Could you test with "echo" instead of var_dump, and see what do you get?

Comment: It's not your `var_dump()` that's displaying the proper json, it's your curl call.  To capture the result instead of displaying it you need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL and PHP displaying "1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909002/curl-and-php-displaying-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample code. It's working fine in my side.

```
<?php
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "your API end point"

    ));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$result = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

//header('Content-Type: application/json');
//echo $result;


$file = 'product.json';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= $result;
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Note : Give destination JSON file as write permission.

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 did it, Thank you!