# Amadeus Flight search api getting error while passing access_token in curl php

Tags: php, api, curl, amadeus

I am integrating amadeus flight search api and getting error while using access_token. I guess problem is at retrieving the access token?

```
{ "errors": [ { "code": "38191", "title": "Invalid HTTP header", "detail": "Missing or invalid format for mandatory Authorization header", "status": "401" } ] }
```

I need to get all the flights from source to destination with price details.

```
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token'); 
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$secretid&client_secret=$secretkey");
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
$data = json_decode($token,true);

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SYD&destinationLocationCode=BKK&departureDate=2020-10-01&returnDate=2020-08-05&adults=2&includedAirlineCodes=TG&max=3');

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer' .$data['access_token']));
$result = curl_exec($curls);
    if (curl_errno($curls)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curls);
    }
//print_r ($result);
curl_close ($curls);
```

Comment: `Missing or invalid format for mandatory Authorization header` Look at the documentation to find out what you missed

Comment: If it really should be sent as Authorization header then space between Bearer and the token might help.

Comment: I guess the problem is at retrieving token and parsing it to authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few mistakes in your code and fixed it to make it work:

1. With the version of PHP you use, you need to add `curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` to make sure it doesn't only print the API response but returns it as well (please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909002/curl-and-php-displaying-1))
2. You need a space between Bearer and the access token: `array('Authorization: Bearer ' .$data['access_token']));`
3. The example you try to call is wrong, the return date is earlier than the departureDate. I changed it for a simpler example: `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=EWR&destinationLocationCode=MIA&departureDate=2020-09-10&returnDate=2020-09-17&adults=1&max=1`. Please take a look at the [API reference documentatio](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference)n to understand the different query parameters you can use.
4. Before doing the API call you need change the `CURLOPT_POST` to false (as the API you are trying to call is a `GET`)

Find below the full example:

```
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$secretid&client_secret=$secretkey");
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$token = curl_exec($curls);
$data = json_decode($token,true);

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=EWR&destinationLocationCode=MIA&departureDate=2020-09-10&returnDate=2020-09-17&adults=1&max=1');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, false);

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' .$data['access_token']));
$result = curl_exec($curls);
    if (curl_errno($curls)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curls);
    }
print_r ($result);
curl_close ($curls);
```

Note: I am not a PHP expert, I am sure the code can be improved.